# All options for combobox in clojure/seesaw

Tags: combobox, clojure, seesaw

So I've created some comboboxes with a variety of elements in alphabetical order. I do not want the default selection on my menu to be the top value; rather, I want it to be the most commonly selected value. In swing I could call the member function `setSelectedIndex()` and simply pass in the index of the most popular menu value. How can I do this in seesaw? The seesaw documentation says the options are `:model` and `:renderer`, but I can't find anything to allow me to set the default index...

Is there additional documentation I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function `selection!` you can use:

```
(defn combotest []
  (let [w (frame :title "Combobox Test" :width 200 :height 80)
        combo (combobox :model ["A" "B" "C"])
        pnl (horizontal-panel :items [combo])]
     (config! w :content pnl)
     (selection! combo "C") ;;  <--- boom ---
     (show! w)))
```

Also, these are still Swing items we're working with, so at the end of the day, we can also do:

```
(.setSelectedIndex combo 2)
```